# Convention for return types from service and controller classes, using Domain Driven Design?

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design

Creating a rest-api, my webservice returns either primitives or dto's, and sometimes domain objects. To be precise my controller classes returns those types, after interacting with service classes that return ... ?

Is their a convention for return types from service classes,  my understanding is domain objects can be used (and therefore returned) in any layer.

Can dto's/value objects/primitives also be returned ?

Is there a convention for return types within application layers using DDD, and also what if not using DDD ?

(Repositories/DAO's return domain objects/entities or collections of)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if there is a convention per say, however here is what we do

- Repositories return only aggregates
- We have the concept of Finders which denote the read side from
  [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), they return only DTO's
- Domain services return Aggregates or Value Objects typically after
  having performed some business logic on either of the above
- Application Services return either DTO's (in case of reads) or
  Identity (Value Objects) in case of writes
- Controllers return DTO's (in case of reads) or Identity (VO) in case 
  of creating something new. Very rarely they return primitives in case
  the request for only to perform some calculation
- Often Controllers use Finders to just return DTO's.